# How to upload multi files to different folders on google drive at the same time

Tags: android, file-upload, google-drive-android-api

firstly, it's my first time i post a question on SO so you can feel free to give me advices if i make something wrong. My question is post's title, i am success to upload multi file to google drive but i can not upload them into different sub folders on drive. Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

Upload class to handle upload function:

```
public class UploadFileActivity  /*implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener*/ {
private static final String TAG = "upload_file";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
public File textFile;
public GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
public static String drive_id;
public static DriveId driveID;
public Context mContext;
public String folder_id;
public  String foler_backup_id;
public String foler_backup_name;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


public void testDrive(){

    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(googleApiClient,folder_id).setResultCallback(idCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> idCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
                if(!driveIdResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                Log.d("check_up", "1");
                driveID = driveIdResult.getDriveId();


                final DriveFolder folder = driveID.asDriveFolder();
                folder.listChildren(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(metadataResult);

               /* Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(googleApiClient)

                        .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);*/
            }
        };

/*callback on getting the drive contents, contained in result*/
final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error creating new file contents");
                    return;
                }
                final DriveFolder folder = driveID.asDriveFolder();

                Log.d("check_folder",folder.toString());
                final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                        addTextfileToOutputStream(outputStream);
                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle(textFile.getName())
                                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                .setDescription("This is a text file uploaded from device")
                                .setStarred(true).build();

                        //root folder
                        /*Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(googleApiClient)
                                .createFile(googleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);*/

                        //file in folder
                        folder.createFile(googleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);

                        //file in app folder
                        /*Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient)
                                .createFile(googleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);*/
                    }

                }.start();
            }
        };

/*get input stream from text file, read it and put into the output stream*/
private void addTextfileToOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
    Log.i(TAG, "adding text file to outputstream...");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    try {
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(textFile));
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "problem converting input stream to output stream: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*callback after creating the file, can get file info out of the result*/
final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error creating the file");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                            "Error adding file to Drive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "File added to Drive");
                Log.i(TAG, "Created a file with content: "
                        + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
                /*Toast.makeText(mContext,
                        "Files successfully added to Drive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                listener.onReceive();
                final PendingResult<DriveResource.MetadataResult> metadata
                        = result.getDriveFile().getMetadata(googleApiClient);
                metadata.setResultCallback(new
                                                   ResultCallback<DriveResource.MetadataResult>() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onResult(DriveResource.MetadataResult metadataResult) {

                                                           Metadata data = metadataResult.getMetadata();
                                                           Log.i(TAG, "Title: " + data.getTitle());
                                                           drive_id = data.getDriveId().encodeToString();
                                                           Log.i(TAG, "DrivId: " + drive_id);
                                                           driveID = data.getDriveId();
                                                           Log.i(TAG, "Description: " + data.getDescription().toString());
                                                           Log.i(TAG, "MimeType: " + data.getMimeType());
                                                           Log.i(TAG, "File size: " + String.valueOf(data.getFileSize()));
                                                       }
                                                   });
            }
        };

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataResult = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    //showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
                    Log.d("check_title", "Problem while retrieving files");
                    return;
                }
                Log.d("check_folder_backup",foler_backup_name);
                for(int i = 0;i<result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount();i++){
                    Metadata metadata = result.getMetadataBuffer().get(i);
                    if(metadata.isFolder()){
                        if(metadata.getTitle().equals(foler_backup_name)){
                            foler_backup_id = metadata.getDriveId().getResourceId();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("check_title",metadata.getTitle() + " " + metadata.isFolder());
                }
                //Log.d("check_folder_backup_id",foler_backup_id);
                if(foler_backup_id==null){
                    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(googleApiClient,folder_id).setResultCallback(preCreateFolder);
                }else {
                    Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(googleApiClient,foler_backup_id).setResultCallback(preCreateFile);
                }

            }
        };

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> preCreateFile = new
        ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
                if(!driveIdResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                Log.d("check_up", "10");
                 driveID = driveIdResult.getDriveId();

                Log.d("check_drive_id",driveID.toString());

                //folder.listChildren(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(metadataResult);

                Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(googleApiClient)

                        .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
            }
        };

final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>preCreateFolder = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult driveIdResult) {
        if(!driveIdResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
            Log.d("Check_error","Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        Log.d("Check_error","4");
        DriveId driveId = driveIdResult.getDriveId();
        DriveFolder folder = driveId.asDriveFolder();
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle(foler_backup_name).build();
        folder.createFolder(googleApiClient,changeSet)
                .setResultCallback(createFolderCallBack);
    }
};

final ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult> createFolderCallBack = new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult driveFolderResult) {
        if(!driveFolderResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
            return;
        }
        Log.d("thong_bao","Folder successfully created");
        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(googleApiClient,foler_backup_id).setResultCallback(preCreateFile);
    }
};


public interface OnCatch{
    public void onReceive();
}

private OnCatch listener;

public void setCatch(OnCatch listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating files based on 1 driveId. You want to create/upload files from different subfolders, you need to have different driveId objects per subfolder.

Another possible solution would be for you to use the Drive REST APIs and call [Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/batch) (thru asynctask) when creating/uploading files in to different subfolders.